# Allow only one user to access a specific AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have admin rights to AWS console.  I have 5 AWS buckets.  I am trying to create a user with object put, delete, get rights to one specific bucket.  I have done the following:

1. Created a 'mathtest' group for the purpose
2. Attached an inline policy to the group.
3. Created a user and attached the user to the 'mathtest' group
4. Provided only programmatic access to the user.
5. Downloaded the credentials file.

The attached policy is as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mathtest"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mathtest/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have also tried the policy given in AWS Documentation:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mathtest",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mathtest/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotAction": "s3:*",
            "NotResource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mathtest",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mathtest/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Using the credentials, I reworked the AWS CLI by using `aws configure`.  My local machine is Ubuntu.

To test the access, when I type:

```
aws s3 ls
```

I get the complete list of all the buckets and when I try to list the contents of buckets other than mathtest, i am able to get the complete list.

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to match the text - If you grant `s3:ListAllMyBuckets` then the user can list all buckets. If you don't want them to be able to do that, remove the action. Your title talks about only allowing one user to access the bucket which may not be the case depending on other users / permissions.

Sorry missed "and when I try to list the contents of buckets other than mathtest, i am able to get the complete list." that shouldn't be the case - perhaps try policysim.aws.amazon.com to see if something else is in play.

Comment: I am denying the permission to listallbuckets... Still I am getting all the buckets listed.